# How change user type from contributor to author

Tags: users, user-roles, sql

I have 2058 users who are *contributors*. I need to convert their role to *author*.

How can do it by SQL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating User Meta with SQL Query](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/136907/updating-user-meta-with-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

**I recommend backing up the database before making any major/bulk changes to it.**

First you need to get all users with the role "contributors", then update their roles to "author".

```
$contributors = get_users(array('role'=>'contributor'));

foreach($contributors as $contributor){

    wp_update_user(array( 'ID' => $contributor->ID, 'role' => "author") );

}
echo "done updating contributors to authors";
```

You could have this script on an empty page template. Just load the page once, for the script to run. Then disable the script.